# A semaphore implmentation with Peterson's N process algorithm

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, operating-system, semaphore

I need feedback on my code for following statement, am I on right path?

Problem statement:

a. Implement a semaphore class that has a private int and three public methods: init, wait and signal. The wait and signal methods should behave as expected from a semaphore and must use Peterson's N process algorithm in their implementation.

b. Write a program that creates 5 threads that concurrently update the value of a shared integer and use an object of semaphore class created in part a) to ensure the correctness of the concurrent updates.

Here is my working program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t mid;                   //muted id
int shared=0;                           //global shared variable
class semaphore {
   int counter;
public:
   semaphore(){
   }
   void init(){
       counter=1;                     //initialise counter 1 to get first thread access
   }
   void wait(){
       pthread_mutex_lock(&mid);         //lock the mutex here
       while(1){
           if(counter>0){             //check for counter value
               counter--;             //decrement counter
               break;                   //break the loop
           }

       }
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&mid);       //unlock mutex here
   }
   void signal(){
       pthread_mutex_lock(&mid);       //lock the mutex here
           counter++;                   //increment counter
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mid);   //unlock mutex here
       }

};
semaphore sm;
void* fun(void* id)
{
   sm.wait();                           //call semaphore wait
   shared++;                           //increment shared variable
   cout<<"Inside thread "<<shared<<endl;
   sm.signal();                       //call signal to semaphore
}


int main() {

   pthread_t id[5];                   //thread ids for 5 threads
   sm.init();
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)                   //create 5 threads
   pthread_create(&id[i],NULL,fun,NULL);
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   pthread_join(id[i],NULL);           //join 5 threads to complete their task
   cout<<"Outside thread "<<shared<<endl;//final value of shared variable
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to release the mutex while spinning in the wait loop.

The test happens to work because the threads very likely run their functions start to finish before there is any context switch, and hence each one finishes before the next one even starts.  So you have no contention over the semaphore.  If you did, they'd get stuck with one waiter spinning with the mutex held, preventing anyone from accessing the counter and hence release the spinner.

Here's an example that works (though it may still have an initialization race that causes it to sporadically not launch correctly).  It looks more complicated, mainly because it uses the gcc built-in atomic operations.  These are needed whenever you have more than a single core, since each core has its own cache.  Declaring the counters 'volatile' only helps with compiler optimization - for what is effectively SMP, cache consistency requires cross-processor cache invalidation, which means special processor instructions need to be used.  You can try replacing them with e.g. counter++ and counter-- (and same for 'shared') - and observe how on a multi-core CPU it won't work.  (For more details on the gcc atomic ops, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>


class semaphore {
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    int32_t counter;
public:
   semaphore() {
       init();

   }
   void init() {
       counter = 1;           //initialise counter 1 to get first access
   }

   void spinwait() {
       while (true) {
           // Spin, waiting until we see a positive counter
           while (__atomic_load_n(&counter, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST) <= 0)
               ;

           pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
           if (__atomic_load_n(&counter, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST) <= 0) {
               // Someone else stole the count from under us or it was
               // a fluke - keep trying
               pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
               continue;
           }
           // It's ours
           __atomic_fetch_add(&counter, -1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
           return;
       }
   }

   void signal() {
       pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);   //lock the mutex here
       __atomic_fetch_add(&counter, 1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); //unlock mutex here
   }

};

enum { 
    NUM_TEST_THREADS = 5,
    NUM_BANGS = 1000
 };

// Making semaphore sm volatile would be complicated, because the
// pthread_mutex library calls don't expect volatile arguments.

int shared = 0;       // Global shared variable
semaphore sm;         // Semaphore protecting shared variable

volatile int num_workers = 0;   // So we can wait until we have N threads


void* fun(void* id)
{
    usleep(100000);                   // 0.1s. Encourage context switch.


    const int worker = (intptr_t)id + 1;

    printf("Worker %d ready\n", worker);

    // Spin, waiting for all workers to be in a runnable state.  These printouts
    // could be out of order.
    ++num_workers;
    while (num_workers < NUM_TEST_THREADS)
        ;

    // Go!

    // Bang on the semaphore.  Odd workers increment, even decrement.
    if (worker & 1) {
        for (int n = 0; n < NUM_BANGS; ++n) {
            sm.spinwait();
            __atomic_fetch_add(&shared, 1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
            sm.signal();
        }
    } else {
        for (int n = 0; n < NUM_BANGS; ++n) {
            sm.spinwait();
            __atomic_fetch_add(&shared, -1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
            sm.signal();
        }
    }

    printf("Worker %d done\n", worker);

    return NULL;
}


int main() {

    pthread_t id[NUM_TEST_THREADS]; //thread ids

    // create test worker threads
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_TEST_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, fun, (void*)((intptr_t)(i)));

    // join threads to complete their task
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_TEST_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_join(id[i], NULL);

    //final value of shared variable.  For an odd number of
    // workers this is the loop count, NUM_BANGS
    printf("Test done.  Final value: %d\n", shared);
    const int expected = (NUM_TEST_THREADS & 1) ? NUM_BANGS : 0;
    if (shared == expected) {
        puts("PASS");
    } else {
        printf("Value expected was: %d\nFAIL\n", expected);
    }

    return 0;
}
```